# Notifications are not working with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to send a local notification when a user reaches a specific phase in the android application built with kotlin.

Here is the code I'm using :

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        pageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PageViewModel::class.java).apply {
            setIndex(arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) ?: 1)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        activity?.let {
            Mapbox.getInstance(
                it,
                getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token2)
            )
        }
        val root =
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation, container, false)
        return root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mapView.getMapAsync(this)
        startTripNotification()
    }

    private fun startTripNotification() {
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity, 0, Intent(), 0)
        val     notification = Notification.Builder(activity)
            .setContentTitle("test notification title")
            .setContentText("test notification text")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_main_icon_round)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
        notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        val notificationManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build())
    }
```

There is no response at all, using Debugging I found out that the function `startTripNotification` is being triggered correctly, but still no notification appears or any response, even in the `logCat` nothing being added at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), notifications require a notification channel. You need to create and attach a notification channel for your notification.

```
private fun initChannel(channelId: String, channelName: String) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26) {
            return
        }
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
```

then in

```
private fun startTripNotification() {

        initChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity, 0, Intent(), 0)
        val     notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(activity,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("test notification title")
            .setContentText("test notification text")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_main_icon_round)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
        notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        val notificationManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build())
    }
```

You can read more about notification channel [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)