# Push Notifications Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, push

I try to create a notification with `notificationBuilder` and `notificationManager`. Everything seems all right but the notification does not appear when the app is in the background nor when it is in the foreground.

Can you help? Here is the code so far:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        Log.i("info", "Message received: ${remoteMessage.from}")

        Log.i("info", remoteMessage.data.toString())

        if (remoteMessage.data != null) {
            showNotification(remoteMessage.data.get("title"), remoteMessage.data.get("text"))
        }


    }


    private fun showNotification(title: String?, body: String?) {

        Log.i("info", "show notification $title    $body")



        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())

    }
}
```

Comment: try to set autoCancel (false) and set channel


```NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default",
                                                          "Channel name",
                                                          NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.setDescription("Channel description");
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);```

Comment: I've added "set channel". Sadly no success.
        val channel: NotificationChannel = NotificationChannel("default", "Channel name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        channel.setDescription("Channel description")
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())



    }
}

Comment: is your onMessageReceived method getting triggered?

Comment: Yes it is as well as showNotification func

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58890967/4686324